# Microsoft Access - Crosstab of a filtered form

Tags: sql, vba, forms, ms-access, filter

I'm trying to generate a report similar to a crosstab. The data are from a filtered form (*Dates* and *WorkerID* (String)).

- form: *frmReg*
- table with data: *tReg*
- report: *reportReg*

On the following line:

```vb
Set qdf = dbsReport.QueryDefs(Me.RecordSource)
```

I'm getting the error:

> Error 3265 Item not found in this collection

What am I doing wrong?

```vb
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
 '  Create underlying recordset for report using criteria

    Dim intX As Integer
    Dim qdf As QueryDef
    Dim frm As Form

    '   Don't open report if frmReg form isn't loaded.
    If Not (IsLoaded("frmReg")) Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "To preview or print this report, you must open " _
                & "frmReg in Form view.", vbExclamation, _
               "Must Open Dialog Box"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '  Set database variable to current database.
    Set dbsReport = CurrentDb
    Set frm = Forms!frmReg

    '  Open QueryDef object.
    ' Set qdf = dbsReport.QueryDefs("ReportReg")
     Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM [tReg]"
     Set qdf = dbsReport.QueryDefs(Me.RecordSource)

    '  Open Recordset object.
    Set rstReport = qdf.OpenRecordset()

    '  Set a variable to hold number of columns in crosstab query.
    intColumnCount = rstReport.Fields.Count
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your drive doing? Please post any code into your topic. Your drive requires access, this is not user friendly.

Comment: My mistake. I added the code "On open" event of the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [QueryDefs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194892.aspx) collection takes saved, named queries and not SQL statements. As @Jiggles32 demonstrates, you need to create a named query and then reference it with `QueryDefs()` call.

However, you can bypass the use of queries by simply directly opening recordsets with [OpenRecordset()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820966.aspx) which is the end result of your needs:

```vb
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [tReg]"

Me.RecordSource = strSQL
Set rstReport = dbsReport.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

'  Set a variable to hold number of columns in crosstab query.
intColumnCount = rstReport.Fields.Count
```

In fact, you can directly extract a form's recordset using [RecordsetClone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Access.Form.RecordsetClone) property (preferred over [Recordset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.recordset) if running various operations to not affect form's actual records):

```vb
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [tReg]"

Me.RecordSource = strSQL
Set rstReport = Me.RecordsetClone

'  Set a variable to hold number of columns in crosstab query.
intColumnCount = rstReport.Fields.Count
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem might be a relationship issue between the SQL and the commands and you probably do not have a query setup to take the information you are seeking.

Try this:

```
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM [tReg]"
Me.RecordSource = sSQL
Set qdf = dbsReport.CreateQueryDef("NewQuery", sSQL)

'This will purge the query after your inteactions are complete
dbsReport.QueryDefs.Delete "NewQuery"
```

*Note: This will not include any interactions for the `QueryDef`.*